# Реализация и использование singleton

Tags: c++, объекты, singleton

Здравствуйте, как создать объект singleton'а?(Например вызывать какой-то метод из singleton) 
Использовать Single&instance =Single::getInstance();

```
class Single{
private:
    Single();
    ~Single();

    Single(const Single&);
    Single& operator=(Single&);
public:
    static Single& getInstance(){
        static Single instance;
        return instance;
    }

};
```

Например вызывать какой-то метод из singleton

```
class Single{
private:
    string name_pr;
    string name_eq;
    Single();
    ~Single();

    Single(const Single&);
    Single& operator=(Single&);
public:
    static Single& getInstance(){
        static Single instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void buy(string name_pr, string name_eq){
        cout << "got it";
    }
};

class Window{
private:
    string name_pr;
    string name_eq;

    public:
        Window(){
            cin >> name_pr >> name_eq;
            Single&instance =Single::getInstance();
            //Single&instance =Single::buy(name_pr,name_eq);
        }
};

int main() {
Window obj;
return 0;
}
```

Что то типу такого.

Comment: Не понял... а в чем вопрос, если вы уже и ответили? :)

Comment: Если я вызываю также Single&instance =Single::getInstance(); любую другую функцию из этого класса, то компилятор выдает ошибку.

Comment: Приведите пример. Что вызываете, как объявлено, какое сообщение об ошибке...

Comment: Ошибки ld returned 1 exit status и еще undefined reference to `Single::~Single()'

Comment: Проверьте наличие реализации всех методов, включая и деструктор.

Comment: Так это ошибка линковщика, у вас нет реализации деструктора. Реализуйте его, надо же как-то объект в конце работы  убивать...

Comment: В классе Window реализуем деструктор для объекта класса Single, правильно?

Comment: плохо понятно, что Вы хотите сделать. Если Window является синглтоном, то код совсем неверный